# Menu highlights all active sub-category items, when item below is hovered (joomla / mosets tree)

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have a Joomla site using Mosets Tree for a business directory. On the right side all the categories are listed. If the sub-categories for an item are expanded, for example under GENERAL SERVICES and you roll over the next menu item (GOVERNMENT AGENCIES), all the sub-category items above get highlighted, which obviously shouldn't happen.

http://www.downtownnewwest.ca/index.php/directory/general-services

The CSS looks like this:

```
#sidebar ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left:0;
}

#sidebar .active ul li a {
  text-transform: none;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


#sidebar ul.menu li a  {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
  color: #00215b;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1pt solid #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar ul.menu li a:hover  {
   background: #00215b;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the [direct child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/child), in order to only select the direct `li` children elements of `ul.menu`. Additionally, the anchor elements should be `inline-block` as opposed to `block`:

This will fix the issues:

```
#sidebar ul.menu > li > a {
    width: 190px;
    color: #00215b;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1pt solid #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```